Windows TerminalでSJISロケールのLinuxにsshし、正常に入出力を行う方法
問題
Localeがja_JP（CP932）に設定されているLinuxサーバーがあります。
そちらにWindows Terminal/PowerShell7でssh接続すると、コマンドエラー等が発生した際のエラー内容等は日本語で返ってくるのですが、文字化けします。
TeraTermであれば、「設定」->「その他の設定」->「Coding」->「receive」を"Japanese/SJIS(CP932)"に設定することで正常に送受信できるようになります。
解決したいこと
おそらく、Windows Terminal/PowerShell7は全ての入出力をUTF-8で行っていると思うのですが、SSHでの通信をSJISとして送受信する設定はあるのでしょうか？

この記事 Problems when using "New Windows Terminal" to ssh into non-UTF codepage servers が類似の問題を扱っていそうです。回答あるいは回答のコメントのluitを使う方法を応用してencodingにSJIS(cp932等?)を指定してみてはどうでしょう？

入出力を UTF-8 に統一してみてはどうでしょうか。具体的には Linuxサーバ側の ~/.bash_profile に export LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 や export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8 を追加します。

profileにユーザロケールを設定する方法でうまくいきました。
ありがとうございます。
